# different screen and different view

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to have a different view with different screen in UWP, For example I have a grid with three columns in UWP app, inside the three columns it has two textboxes and button or other control. I want to change the Grid's column and row based on the screen size. When the screen size is more than 1000, the grid will have one row with three columns . when is more than 600 it will have two row, or it will have three row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UWP app, if you want to show different content/view based on the different screen size, we can use the [AdaptiveTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to implement the adaptive UI.

The **AdaptiveTrigger** class has only two parameters: **MinWindowWidth** and **MinWindowHeight**. These two parameters allow us to switch state of window based on the different screen size.

For the detailed information, please check:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/06/26/uwp-new-features-of-visual-state-manager-part-1/  .

In order to implement your scenario, I have created the following example, please try to refer to:

```
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="ThreeColumns">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MyTextBox1.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyTextBox1.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyTextBox2.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyTextBox2.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="2"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyButton.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyButton.Content" Value="This is one Row"></Setter>
                </VisualState.Setters>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1000"></AdaptiveTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="TwoColumns">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MyTextBox1.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyTextBox2.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyTextBox1.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyTextBox2.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyButton.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="MyButton.Content" Value="This is Two Row"></Setter>
                </VisualState.Setters>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600"></AdaptiveTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid Height="500">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox1" Grid.Row="0" Height="50"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox2" Grid.Row="1" Height="50"></TextBox>
        <Button Name="MyButton" Background="Red" Content="This is Three Row" Grid.Row="2" Height="50"></Button>
    </Grid>
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Cool, thank you so much. What if I want to change the content of the row and column. For example in one row three buttons, in two row two buttons, one textbox. in three row three textboxes? How to achieve it?

Comment: We can modify the visible of the control in the visualstate.

Comment: Thank you. I have open a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255941/expanded-from-differen-screen-and-different-view  
can you share me the code