# Why is my VisualStateTrigger not updating?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, converters, win-universal-app

I have following situation:
I have a split-view containing of two listviews. The left ones item-selection triggers the right ones content. If the window-width is smaller than 960px i'd like to hide one of the lists depending on the left-listview-selection.

wider than 960px:

|1|2|

smaller than 960px and selectedIndex == -1

|1|

smaller than 960px and selectedIndex >= 0

|2|

My approach is doing this by a converter:

```
class WindowStateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //Debugger.Break();
        if (Window.Current.Bounds.Width > 960) return 1;
        if ((int)value == -1) return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

in my xaml, I am using the CompareStateTrigger from the WindowsStateTriggers Library found on NuGet in this way:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo.IsTargetElement="True">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind SelectionList.SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource wsc}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                  CompareTo="1" Comparison="Equal"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="360"/>
                    <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="narrowDetailView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind SelectionList.SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource wsc}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                  CompareTo="0" Comparison="Equal"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="narrowListView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind SelectionList.SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource wsc}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                  CompareTo="-1" Comparison="Equal"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                    <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ListColumn" Width="0"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DetailColumn" Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="SelectionList"
              Background="LightBlue"
              Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ListView x:Name="DetailsList"
              Background="LightGreen"
              Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

On start, this works fine, but when I change the Window-Size in runtime, nothing happens. I even placed Debbuger.Break() inside my converter for checking if it does something, but it doesn't. Do you have any idea for a solution?

EDIT:

I followed the description for CompositeStateTrigger, my XAML looks like this now:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWPTicketverwaltung.Views.OverviewPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWPTicketverwaltung.Views"
    xmlns:triggers="using:WindowsStateTriggers"
    xmlns:converters="using:UWPTicketverwaltung.Converters" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:WidthConverter x:Key="screenWidth"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo.IsTargetElement="True">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="wideAll">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <triggers:AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="960"/>
                        <!--<triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource screenWidth}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      CompareTo="959" Comparison="GreaterThan"/>-->
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="360"/>
                        <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="narrowOverview">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                            <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind SelectionList.SelectedIndex, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                          CompareTo="-1" Comparison="Equal"/>
                            <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource screenWidth}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                          CompareTo="960" Comparison="LessThan"/>
                        </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="narrowDetails">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                            <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind SelectionList.SelectedIndex, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                          CompareTo="-1" Comparison="GreaterThan"/>
                            <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource screenWidth}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                          CompareTo="960" Comparison="LessThan"/>
                        </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ListColumn" Width="360"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DetailColumn" Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="SelectionList"
                  Background="LightBlue"
                  Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ListView x:Name="DetailsList"
                  Background="LightGreen"
                  Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And my WidthConverter looks like this:

```
public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    { /*Debugger.Break();*/ return Window.Current.Bounds.Width; }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

On start everything looks fine, but when I change the window-size, the trigger does not fire. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Also my Converter fires only once at startup.

EDIT 2:

I followed the instructions and Bound the second CompareStateTrigger to the Grid.Width. This is my XAML, it does not use converters anymore:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" 
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo.IsTargetElement="True">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="wideAll">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind MainGrid.Width, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                  CompareTo="959" Comparison="GreaterThan"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="420"/>
                    <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="narrowOverview">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                        <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind SelectionList.SelectedIndex, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      CompareTo="-1" Comparison="Equal"/>
                        <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind MainGrid.Width, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      CompareTo="960" Comparison="LessThan"/>
                    </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                    <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="narrowDetails">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                        <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind SelectionList.SelectedIndex, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      CompareTo="-1" Comparison="GreaterThan"/>
                        <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind MainGrid.Width, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      CompareTo="960" Comparison="LessThan"/>
                    </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ListColumn" Width="420"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DetailColumn" Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="SelectionList"
              Background="LightBlue"
              Grid.Column="0">
        <!--<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                            <triggers:CompareStateTrigger/>
                        </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>-->
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="DetailsList"
              Background="LightGreen"
              Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

The Problem now is, that the Width-Property seems not to be used at all, since the only state choosen is the "narrowOverview" (even if the app starts wider than 960). Is the way of Binding to the Grid.Width wrong?

Comment: Try AdaptiveTrigger. Here is the link for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255941/expanded-from-differen-screen-and-different-view/36256125#36256125

Comment: It seems you did not read my full question, screen-width is not the only criteria.

Comment: When you change the width it doesnt call converter because width is not bound to value property.

Comment: What you can do is bind width property to value instead of SelectionList.SelectedIndex. you can change the visual state when selected index changed in SelectionChanged event.

Comment: true, but I want to avoid code-behind, especialy in this case.

Comment: Use CompositeStateTrigger for that. here is a link https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers/blob/master/src/TestApp/Samples/CompositeSample.xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CompositeStateTrigger for that. here is a [link](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers/blob/master/src/TestApp/Samples/CompositeSample.xaml)

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="MainGrid">

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="wideAll">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                            <triggers:CompareStateTrigger  Value="{x:Bind SelectionList.SelectedIndex,Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      CompareTo="-1" Comparison="GreaterThan"/>
                            <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind  PageViewModel.ScreenWidth,Mode=OneWay}"
                                                  CompareTo="960" Comparison="GreaterThan"/>
                        </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="420"/>
                        <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <!--blue-->
                <VisualState x:Name="narrowOverview">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                            <triggers:CompareStateTrigger  Value="{x:Bind SelectionList.SelectedIndex,Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      CompareTo="-1" Comparison="Equal"/>
                           <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind  PageViewModel.ScreenWidth,Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      CompareTo="960" Comparison="LessThan"/>
                        </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <!--Green-->
                <VisualState x:Name="narrowDetails">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                            <triggers:CompareStateTrigger  Value="{x:Bind SelectionList.SelectedIndex,Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      CompareTo="-1" Comparison="GreaterThan"/>
                            <triggers:CompareStateTrigger Value="{x:Bind PageViewModel.ScreenWidth,Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      CompareTo="960" Comparison="LessThan"/>
                        </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="ListColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ListColumn" Width="420"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DetailColumn" Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="SelectionList"
              Background="LightBlue"
              Grid.Column="0" >
        </ListView>
        <ListView x:Name="DetailsList"
              Background="LightGreen"
              Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
```

**Mainpage.xaml.cs**

Define ViewModel property here. Assign Vm to DataContext in constructor

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    ViewModel viewModel;
    public ViewModel PageViewModel
      {
         get
         {
                return viewModel;

        }
        set
        {
        if(viewModel!=value)
          {
           viewModel= value;
             OnPropertyChanged("PageViewModel");
           }
        }
     }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
         {
            // the new Null-conditional Operators are thread-safe:
         this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));      

       }

public MainPage()
{
                               this.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;
                                PageViewModel=(ViewModel) DataContext;
 }

            private void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
            {
             PageViewModel.ScreenWidth =(int)     Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
                                Debug.WriteLine(Vm.ScreenWidth);
            }

            }
```

**Class1.cs**

public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

```
        int screenWidth;
        public int ScreenWidth
        {
            get
            {
                return screenWidth;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value!=screenWidth)
                {
                    screenWidth = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ScreenWidth");
                }
            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            // the new Null-conditional Operators are thread-safe:
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did, but it seems like the problem stayes the same. See my Edit

Comment: Is there any problem in using AdaptiveTrigger. You have used ComaprisionTrigger for windows width

Comment: Yes, I use them because AdaptiveTrigger has no MaxWindowWidth property. with Compare I'm able to prevent the narrowDetails/narrowSelector-State from being choosen, since the Condition for SelectedIndex will allways be -1 or larger than -1

Comment: Is screenwidth converter calling when you change the width?

Comment: Give a name to grid and bind it's width property to your second CompareStateTrigger. I think it works that way

Comment: I try to bind the grid-width-property, but it seems it's not working. See all the changes I made in EDIT 2

Comment: Try with ActualWidth. What were you doing with Screenwidth converter?

Comment: It's still the same with ActualWidth. I replaced the ScreenWidth converter by the Grid.Width-Binding

Comment: Found the issue: the Grid.ActualWidth is 0 and Grid.Width = NaN because the Grid is not fully loaded, when the Trigger is calling. The Problem with "visualstate is not updating" still stays the same, I use a Converter as BreakPoint inside the Trigger, and it is only called once, but not when the Window-Size is changing

Comment: Use both converter and Grid.ActualWidth. So that converter gets called when width is changing

Comment: It still does not what it should, since the trigger is only called on startup, but not when changing the width at runtime. If so, it probably would work

Comment: Finally i made it to work. You have to use property defined in your viewmodel. I ll update my answer

Comment: Let me know if you have any problems in the solution

Comment: I'm strugling with the implementation of protected void "OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {...}" since at the moment I'm doing this in Code-Behind and PropertyChangedEventArgs is not accessable. As soon as I have excluded the code behind I will tell the result.

Comment: OnPropertyChanged is very important. you have to implement it properly

Comment: I don't get it. When I'm placing the OnPropertyChanged-method in my OverviewPage.xaml.cs the "new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)" has an error.
The acces on PropertyChangedEventArgs is blocked because of it's protection. Is your MainPage.xaml.cs a "public sealed partial class" and inheriting from Page? If so, what do I need to change?

Comment: Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: That's the problem. When I do so, visual-studio tells me "the access on INotifyPropertyChanged is not possible because of its level of protection". I have the suspicion, this has something to do with UWP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107848/discussion-between-archana-and-raymond-osterbrink).

Comment: How did you manage the binding of DataContext? I'm binding it to Self in Xaml and getting an error: "can't cast Page to Class1" 
when: Vm = (Class1)DataContext

Comment: What is the type of your datacontext? How are you setting it in xaml.cs? I have assigned it to instance of Class1 in constructor.

Comment: In my case it is Page, but I set the DataContext to Page because it was not set before, which led to an error because it was 'null' when OverviewPage_SizeChanged was called on PageLoad.

Comment: Lets continue in chat